# boost::optional assignment with msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

Using the msvc2017 compiler and boost 1.65.1, the the code below doesn't compile.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

boost::optional<double>
foo()
{
    return boost::optional<double>(4.0);
}

int
main(void)
{
    boost::optional<double> result;
    result = foo();
}
```

The error being generated is:

```
C:/boost/optional/optional.hpp(954): error C2248: 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::optional_base': cannot access protected member declared in class 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>'
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
C:/boost/optional/optional.hpp(157): note: see declaration of 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::optional_base'
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
C:/boost/optional/optional.hpp(771): note: see declaration of 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>'
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
C:/boost/optional/optional.hpp(954): note: while checking that elided copy-constructor 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::optional_base(const boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T> &)' is callable
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
C:/boost/optional/optional.hpp(157): note: see declaration of 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::optional_base'
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
C:/boost/optional/optional.hpp(954): note: when converting from 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>' to 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T> &&'
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
C:/boost/optional/optional.hpp(953): note: while compiling class template member function 'boost::optional<double> &boost::optional<double>::operator =(boost::optional<double> &&) noexcept'
main.cpp(13): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::optional<double> &boost::optional<double>::operator =(boost::optional<double> &&) noexcept' being compiled
main.cpp(5): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional<double>' being compiled
```

This problem does not occur for other compilers (I tested both clang and gcc). So this seems like a Microsoft compiler bug to me?

Comment: try `return 4.0;`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Nice first question. Boost version and C++ version ?

Comment: For me it compiles with vs2017 and boost. No additional project settings, but old boost version.

Comment: It compiles for me as well using vs15.5.1 and boost 1.65.1 and the project set to use either c++17 or c++ latest.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me. Forgot to mention these indeed... I'll update the original post. Boost version is 1.65.1, and I was building this example in our existing project structure using qmake. I'll start fresh with a clean project without any compiler flags and narrow it down.

Comment: Got it. In our project we're disabling the Microsoft C / C++ language extensions. So with the /Za compiler option added, this doesn't compile...